# using matlab fscanf for nexstar telescope

Tags: matlab, serial-port, scanf

I am having a problem getting come return values from my telescope. I have been able to send data to it and I am using fscanf to get the return values this is my code so far.

```
close all; clear all; clc;
priorPorts = instrfind; % finds any existing Serial Ports in MATLAB
delete(priorPorts); % and deletes them
COMnum = input('COM Number:');
telescope = serial(['COM',num2str(COMnum)]);
set(telescope,'BaudRate',9600);
set(telescope,'Terminator','#'); %theres a pound symbol at the end of all commands
fopen(telescope);
fprintf(telescope,'h');
out = fscanf(telescope,'%c',512);
```

when i run this out is returned as a string of characters that i cannot interpret (such as "  9  ø"). the expected response is:

```
chr(Q) &
chr(R) &
chr(S) &
chr(T) &
chr(U) &
chr(V) &
chr(W) &
chr(X) &
"#”
```

where Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X are all integers, the "#" is the terminator. 
also when I enter a command that returns a char(integer) & "#" it returns whitespace and the "#" terminator. 
NOTE: this program does work when the return value is only a string of text
what I've tried:

1. changing the %c to other types like %x
2. researching the nexstar programming website and the troubleshooting suggestions there like having it in tracking mode

Here are some of the resources I've been using
http://www.nexstarsite.com/PCControl/ProgrammingNexStar.htm
especially the coms protocol documentation which is the first link at the top.
any and all help is appreciated. thank you!

Comment: I haven't read the full doc in your link but it look like your equipment is sending `byte`(s). So you'd better read `uint8` from the serial port instead of `char`. (Use `fread` instead of `fscanf`). It also look like sometimes the telescope send "high byte, then low byte", so when you expect such an answer, read the 2 bytes then use `typecast` to rebuild a 16bit values.

Comment: @Hoki i used 'fread(telescope,telescope.BytesAvailable,'uint8');' and it returned integers sometimes and sometimes i get an error "size must be greater than zero"  the integers it returns vary in array size and are non nonsensical

Comment: "size must be greater than zero" must be because you specify `size` as `BytesAvailable`. If there are no byte available in the telescope buffer it  returns 0 and error. You have to check if `BytesAvailable>0` before you try to read. The size of the byte array returned is depending on which command you sent to the hardware. How to interpret these byte is detailed in your communication protocol link.

Comment: the command 'h' always returns data, so im not understanding how im getting this error

Comment: just before your call to `fread`, place the following line of code: `disp(num2str(telescope.BytesAvailable))`. That will tell you if this is the problem.

Comment: found the solution to the problem! use fscanf then convert the output as double. i'll put it as the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use fscanf then type cast as double like so

```
out = fscanf(s);
out = double(out);
```